# moment.js isValid function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I have this question... I haven't found anything similar and it also seems very strange that nobody had this problem validating time with moment.js.

```
moment('03:55', 'HH:mm').isValid(); //true
moment('03:55jojojo', 'HH:mm').isValid(); //true
moment('03:55jojojo', 'HH:mm',true).isValid(); //true
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vCGAp/145/

Comment: I can only guess that they explicitly test that the format you pass is tested... but there's no check for "is value the same length as format?"... I'd suggest to try submitting a bug report to moment.js

Comment: ...why do you have those extra characters in the first place? Does it correctly validate longer date-strings against that format?

Comment: what do you mean with extra characters?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

In your question you write that `moment('03:55jojojo', 'HH:mm',true).isValid();` returns true. This is incorrect. Please check your jsfiddle again.

From http://momentjs.com/docs/

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired
>   behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last
>   argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires
>   that the format and input match exactly.

```
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();        // true
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();  // false
moment('2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();        // true
```

You can use both language and strictness.

```
moment('2012-10-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'fr', true);
```

Comment: true (index):26
true (index):27
true (index):29

This is the console log output :S

Comment: If you check your jsfiddle, you'll notice that you are NOT passing true as a third argument anywhere, but in your question you state that `moment('03:55jojojo', 'HH:mm',true).isValid();` returns true. Please run that exact code in your browser - the output is false.

Comment: moment('13/13/2000').isValid() returns true. You must include the format designation for it to validate properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to necro this 5 year old question, but I indeed stumbled upon a case where monent is not working properly towards the documentation, using version 2.24.0.

[image: Formats]

In the picture we can see that for example `H` should only evaluate to `0 - 23`, but if I use `moment('01', 'H', true).isValid()` I still get `true`.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wofgst5v/