# Best Way To Validate a Date String With a Dynamic Date Format

Tags: javascript

There is a dynamic date format where user can specify it somewhere. I need to validate the user input (most likely via js) on a date field when he input it manually (not via datepicker).

I tried moment.js but string date like '30-01-20167' is still valid even if the date format is 'dd-MM-yyyy'

I mean is there really a reliable way to do this?

Comment: Look at this Post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978953/moment-js-isvalid-function-not-doing-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY";
moment('30-01-20167',dateFormat, true).isValid();  // false;
moment('30-01-2016',dateFormat, true).isValid();  // true;
```

PS: It's better to show your code directly.

Comment: Is there any way to check the same without moment.js and using Intl DateTimeFormat or core js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `Date` to evaluate your string:

```js
function isValidDate(dateStr) {
  return !isNaN(new Date(dateStr));
}

console.log(
  isValidDate('30-01-20167'),
  isValidDate('12-30-2016')
)
```