# moment.js isValid for a string in JSON date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date in string format as

```
var addedDate = "2016-10-03T00:00:00.000Z";
```

How to check if this string

- is a date?
- is in the JSON date format?

After doing some research I see that I can check using isValid method in Moment.js

```
moment(addedDate, formatToCheck).isValid();
```

how should look "formatToCheck" format

```
formatToCheck=???
```

Comment: You aren't required to pass a format: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

Comment: @lux. But I want to check if string is in JSON date format too.

Comment: "_the JSON date format_"...? JSON doesn't specify date formats...

Comment: @JAAulde is correct. JSON does not support date objects, it converts these to Strings.

Comment: @lux that's not quite what I'm saying. First, to your comment that JSON converts Date objects to strings, no, JSON doesn't convert anything. Various serializers on various platforms perform the serialization to JSON in various ways. Second, what I was saying is that the format of strings that represent dates is _not_ dictated by the JSON spec.

Comment: @JAAulde You're being pedantic. Obviously JSON itself does not convert anything; it's text. I think it's clear I was referring to `JSON.stringify()` in terms of object serialization. And to your second point, of course, that's implied by virtue they don't support dates, so of course there's no standard format to represent them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
moment('2016-10-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();
```

To check the full format,i guess you can do something like this

```
moment('2016-10-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ms').isValid();
```

Comment: Thanks Geeky. This works. But I want to get only JSON (is it correct way to say?) date strings, which means full check.

Comment: Do you want to check the complete date ,not just year month and date ..is that what you meant

Comment: Yes, complete date, not just a yeas month day.

Comment: modified check it ,if it works..these resources could be helpful to u http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978953/moment-js-isvalid-function-not-working-properly

Comment: Moment.js has a built-in constant value for this format: `moment.ISO_8601`

Comment: @Thanks Mike ...thats nice to know

Answer (score 0):

var addedDate = "2016-10-03T00:00:00.000Z";
Then how to assign value for year month and day from he above string in json format like 
Year: value, month:value, day: value