# Check if a given time string is valid?

Tags: momentjs

I have recently started using momentJS. One thing I want to validate if my given string is valid time or not.

For example

> 12:10am-12:20am - it is valid

But when I do the following:

```
moment("12:10am-12:20am","Hh:Mm").isValid() 
false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: moment takes one time and checks its validity ,this is moment("12:10am","hh:mm").isValid() correct format of doing it...what ever u have done is nt a valid one

Comment: But there is one problem @Geeky if i do moment("12:10amm","hh:mm").isValid() it still returns true :-(

Comment: Make it like this moment("12:10amm","hh:mm",true).isValid() ,for strict formatting .probably this link could be of some help to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978953/moment-js-isvalid-function-not-working-properly