# Moment.js library won't work, reads in invalid inputs as valid

Tags: momentjs

I'm using the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library to read different date formats and approve them as valid or invalid. I found that it read a string of words as valid date input, the string was 'Ref Load v1'. When i separated each word, it turns out that it's accepting 'v1' as valid date format and returning "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000". How can I fix this problem?

Here are my print statements from the command line:

```
moment("1996-01-24T00:00:00.000")
true
moment("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000")
true
moment.invalid(/* Ref */)
false
moment.invalid(/* Load */)
false
moment("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000")
```

Some Code:

```js
function isDate(string) {
  //var moment = require('moment');
  console.log(moment(string, ["MMMM DD, YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD", "M/DD/YYYY",
    "MM/DD/YY", "YYYY-MMM-DD",
    "MMM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MMM-YYYY",
    "YYYYMMDD", "DDMMYY", "YYYY.DDD"
  ]));
  return (String(moment(string, ["MMMM DD, YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD", "M/DD/YYYY",
    "MM/DD/YY", "YYYY-MMM-DD",
    "MMM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MMM-YYYY",
    "YYYYMMDD", "DDMMYY", "YYYY.DDD"
  ])) !== "Invalid date");
}
//exports.isDate = isDate;

console.log(isDate('Jan 24 1996'));
console.log(isDate('Ref Load v1'));
console.log(isDate('Ref'));
console.log(isDate('Load'));
console.log(isDate('v1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The output for the first print statement should be true, everything else should be false.

Comment: This is why [Moment's Parsing Guide recommends using Strict Mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) (in other words, pass true as a third argument to `moment(string, formats, strict)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment.js isValid function not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978953/moment-js-isvalid-function-not-working-properly)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Completely missed that when I was looking at documentation.

Comment: "January 8, 1999" doesn't match a format in your list. "January 08, 1999" does.