# ElementRef is not working Angular 8 with Bsdatepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

What i need

- i need to get date value from textbox and bind format date to textbox.

Problem

> when enter date bsdatepicker is changing date format.

Angular code

```
            import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
            import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

            @Component({
              selector: 'my-app',
              templateUrl: './app.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
              encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
            })
            export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
              myDateValue: Date;
              customInitDate:Date;
              bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
              @ViewChild('dp', {static: false}) dpicker: ElementRef;
              ngOnInit() {
                this.myDateValue = new Date();
               // this.bsConfig = Object.assign({},'');
              }

              onDateChange(newDate: any) {
                console.log(newDate);
                console.log(this.dpicker.nativeElement);
                this.customInitDate=newDate;
              }
            }
```

Html code

```
        <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        #dp
        [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY' }"
        value="{{ customInitDate | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}"
        bsDatepicker
        [(bsValue)]="myDateValue"
        [(ngModel)]="customInitDate"
        (ngModelChange)="onDateChange($event)"
        >
        </div>
```

Bsdatepicker object

```
        BsDatepickerComponent {_config: {…}, placement: "bottom", triggers: "click", outsideClick: true, container: "body", …}
        isOpen: (...)
        _config:
        containerClass: "theme-green"
        displayMonths: 1
        showWeekNumbers: true
        dateInputFormat: "DD-MMM-YYYY"
        rangeSeparator: " - "
        rangeInputFormat: "L"
        locale: "en"
        monthTitle: "MMMM"
        yearTitle: "YYYY"
        dayLabel: "D"
        monthLabel: "MMMM"
        yearLabel: "YYYY"
        weekNumbers: "w"
        value: null
        isDisabled: undefined
        minDate: undefined
        maxDate: undefined
        __proto__: Object
        placement: "bottom"
        triggers: "click"
        outsideClick: true
        container: "body"
        bsValueChange: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(2), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
        _subs: (2) [Subscriber, Subscriber]
        containerClass: "theme-green"
        displayMonths: 1
        showWeekNumbers: true
        dateInputFormat: "L"
        rangeSeparator: " - "
        rangeInputFormat: "L"
        locale: "en"
        monthTitle: "MMMM"
        yearTitle: "YYYY"
        dayLabel: "D"
        monthLabel: "MMMM"
        yearLabel: "YYYY"
        weekNumbers: "w"
        _datepicker: ComponentLoader {_viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef_, _renderer: RendererAdapter, _elementRef: ElementRef, _injector: NgModuleRef_, _componentFactoryResolver: CodegenComponentFactoryResolver, …}
        onShown: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
        onHidden: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
        _bsValue: Fri Dec 08 1989 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
        bsConfig: {dateInputFormat: "DD-MMM-YYYY"}
        minDate: undefined
        maxDate: undefined
        _datepickerRef: ComponentRef_ {_view: {…}, _viewRef: ViewRef_, _component: BsDatepickerContainerComponent, _elDef: {…}}
        __proto__: Object
```

Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-testing-2e2eyu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

But its working without bsdatepicker

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-testing-13hrji?file=app/app.component.ts

> console.log(this.dpicker.nativeElement);
>
> ```
> undefined
> ```

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Do you want to get value using ViewChild?

Comment: i want to get textbox value , by any method .bsdatepicker changing date format or undfined

Comment: have you tried ngModelChange $event argument to get textbox value?

Comment: yes i tried but i get wrong value due to bsdatepicker my second stackblitz work without bsdatepicker

Comment: yes dd-mmm-yyyy , problem was if type 27/8/1999 then default input format changed dateformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BsDatepickerComponent has injected ElementRef as private filed, use that to get BsDatepickerComponent input field value. Change your ViewChild type to BsDatepickerComponent

**Try this**

```
@ViewChild('dp') dpicker: BsDatepickerComponent;

onDateChange(newDate: any) {
    console.log(newDate);
    this.dpicker['_datepicker']['_elementRef'].nativeElement.value
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-testing-6d5bjf)

Comment: Thanks for the help. but still 24/7/1999 its doesn't work output null  and date if tried 12/6/1987 bsdatepicker convert to 06-Dec-1987 but i need 12-dec-1987

Comment: As per given date format(dd-mmm-yyyy). If you type this value 12/6/1987. It's converting correct only

Comment: problem here is user can type 24/7/1986 it we should get 24/7/1986 by element ref

Comment: i dont need changed format value done bsdatepicker ,i need textbox value bsdatepicker changing dateformat that's why i cannot use of texbox value from elementref

Comment: I think, It's possible to set dynamic date format in bsdatepicker

Comment: thanks for understanding problem bsdatepicker changing date format . i was binding ngmodel after get value from texbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978953/moment-js-isvalid-function-not-working-properly  givee me what about bsdatepicker not giving correct texbox val

Comment: When you place bsdatepicker on input element input, Input element turned to custom form control that's why not able to get input value

Comment: many thanks any solution for this problem i wasted week still stucked  here

Comment: i looked into custom form accessor https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206766/discussion-between-chellappan--and-afeef).